# IIS trace log shows success but content encoding is not present in response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, iis, http-compression

I have enabled gzip in IIS. From the failed request log I can see dynamic compression is success. But the content encoding is not present in response headers.Please suggest a solution, see the settings below:

```
Response Header

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 16:12:04 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Request Headers

Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Content-Length:68
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

> DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_START 
>   GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER HeaderName="Vary", HeaderValue="Accept-Encoding", Replace="false"
>   DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_SUCCESS 
>   DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_DO  OriginalSize="266271", CompressedSize="30223"
>   DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_END

web.config compression settings:

```
 <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" minFileSizeForComp="2700" noCompressionForHttp10="false" noCompressionForProxies="false">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" />
    <serverRuntime frequentHitThreshold="1" frequentHitTimePeriod="10:00:00" />
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  Did you find a answer?